# Can't get beyond desktop on TV screen on dual display setup

Tags: display, tv

Using older PC running Ubuntu. Trying to stream video to HD TV via VGA cable. On startup, desktop visible on both PC Monitor and TV screen. Mouse is shown and active on PC screen only. Can run software and view folders on PC but TV screen is stuck on desktop and shows nothing else regardless of what shows on PC. How do I get the TV screen to move past the desktop image.

Comment: In your Settings > Display, is it set to `Mirror displays`?

Comment: Thank you ankit7540, works like a charm. Just a novice on Linux.